# duplicate assemblies in a clickonce deployment

Tags: .net, clickonce

I'm investiguating clickonce deployment for a .NET application.  This application contains a duplicated sets a assemblies  (in different folders).  The reason is that this application embed an asp.net web site that is used in-process.  The winform app and the web site a sharing a set of dll for business logic and core plumbing.

When i generate the app manifest using MageUI.exe, i get warnings about duplicated assemblies, but the manifest is created anyway.

When i try to install this application, it seems the manifest is declared malformed by clickonce.

Is it possible that duplicated assemblies are the cause of this ?  Is there a way to support that with clickonce ?

thanks a lot.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally had success using the  config element

Comment: As @redcalx mentioned. Can you please elaborate? Your solution would be helpful. Don't be selfish.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the GAC. I'm not sure if that will fix the issue or not. You could also try a common assembly folder. In other words, removing the duplicates, but trying to have the same end result.

Comment: I will investigate the use of the <probing> config tag to group common assemblies in same folder.  Thanks